# SED search for a block of text and add text right before the end of that block of text

Tags: bash, sed

Require some help. Been trying to use sed to search for a block of text from httpd.conf and right after the search, use sed to add text at the block of text. This is an example.

```
sed -n '/<Directory "\/var\/www\/html">/,/<\/Directory>/p' httpd.conf
```

After that pipe this output to sed again to insert text right before the  which will look like this:

```
<Directory "/var/www/html">
. . .
# Limit HTTP methods
<LimitExcept GET POST OPTIONS>
Require all denied
</LimitExcept>
</Directory>
```

However after trying alot of different ways still cant get what i want. Anyone can help ? hope this is not a duplicate issue.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed);

```
sed -i -e '\#<Directory "/var/www/html"#,/<\/Directory>/{/<\/Directory>/i\INSERTED' -e '}' file
```

Use a range `/first regexp/,/second regexp/command` and repeat the second regexp with a following insert command.

Comment: it does work but i need it to be written in the file using -i option. i replace the -e to -i ?

Comment: is there a way to make the changes permanent? the way u provide works but its not permanent. i cant output it to a new file and replace the old file again.

Comment: I am marking this answer as correct. "/var/www/html"# this does not work.. however i should use \ to escape the / .. Thank you for the answer..